# Azure Site to Site Behind a NAT

Tags: azure, vpn, nat

We are looking to setup a Site to Site VPN connection between our internal data center and Azure. We use a CISCO ASA firewall but unfortunately it is behind a NAT. One of the requirements for Azure is that the public facing IP address is not behind a NAT.

There doesn't seem to be interest on our side to change our network topology and was wondering if anyone had any creative solutions to make it work? Couldn't find any creative workarounds on Google or on SO.

The VPN connection appears to be made in the Azure Portal but the connection doesn't work between on prem and Azure VM's. I'd post an image of the Azure Portal showing the connection being made but apparently I don't have enough of a repuptation to post images...

Creative ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your only choice would be to utilise a Point-to-Site VPN where a device behind your NAT does the termination. https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-point-to-site-create/

You'll be restricted in terms of what you can do with this VPN as it's designed primiarily as a server-to-Azure VPN solution.

There are a few posts floating about around getting VPN working via a NAT'd interface but your mileage may vary in that case and you'll be running an unsupported setup.